# Why does adding float give different result depending on how its performed

Tags: c#, floating-accuracy

I have run in to an issue when adding floats in C#. The following is taken from the immediate window in Visual Studio. I have declared f as float, and now do a simple calculation in two different ways:

```
f = 5.75f + 0.075f*37
8.525001
f = 0.075f*37
2.775
f = f + 5.75f
8.525
```

As you can see the results differ between the two ways of doing the same calculation. How can that be. As i see it, the numbers are nowhere near the precision limit of the float, so what is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As i see it, the numbers are nowhere near the precision limit of the float

They really are - or rather, the difference is.

The *exact* values involved are 8.52500057220458984375 (rounded up to 8.525001 for display) and 8.5249996185302734375 (rounded up to 8.525 for display). The difference between those two values is 0.0000009536743164062. Given that `float` only has 7 decimal digits of precision (as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx)), that's a pretty reasonable inaccuracy, in my view.

It's not actually the ordering of the operations that matters here. You get *exactly* the same results if you switch them round:

```
float f = 0.075f * 37 + 5.75f;
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(f));
f = 5.75f;
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(f));
f = f + 0.075f * 37;
Console.WriteLine(DoubleConverter.ToExactString(f));
```

(Using my [`DoubleConverter`](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs) class.)

The difference is that in the first version, *all* the information is available in one go - and actually at compile-time. The compiler does the arithmetic, and I suspect it actually performs it at a higher accuracy, and then reduces the accuracy of the overall *result* to 32 bits afterwards.

Comment: What I meant by the values not being near the precision was that the maximum in the example is 4 digits, but I guess that's about precision vs accuracy. I was not really questioning the order of the operations, but the fact that the value changed when doing it in two steps instead of one. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Keller: Well if you only look at them to 4 significant digits then they *are* equal :)